# Center full screen div with margin

Tags: html, css, overflow

I don't know how to center a full screen div.
I want to center a div with `width: 90%` and `height: 90%`, but when I use this code:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.outer {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
</div>
```

I get a little bit of scroll that I don't want.

Comment: Just a quick tip... if you get a bit of scroll you dont want, I suggest you look into the css overflow property!

Answer (score 3):

**Use this:**

```
html,body {
    margin: 0;
   //other codes...
}
```

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.outer {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.inner {
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">

    </div>
</div>
```